# Any sample of simple data management app ? WPF+ C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008, mvvm, line-of-business-app

I have learned about programming for 3 years from Assembly to BASIC to C and WPF, but I wonder that inside the reference book, did't much help me in creating a simple/ complex , a complete system. I never touch C# before and its totally different between C# and WPF, many source code provide a separate program without link to database , and when i tried to connected to database, my application is malfunction. I try to find a complete sample  LOB app,but when i figure out why i download from Codeproject is very complicated ....and its MVVM ... a more complicated than what i think. I need a professional give me an advice ...I am a graduated diploma student and a WPF self learner.

Comment: Why not make your own example? Like a librairy! Create a Database in SQL Server and add tables for Books, Users, and figure out a way to track who has what book borrowed. Simply look up how to connect to your database with the right ConnectionString and get started!

Answer (score 1):

i think u should read good books about CLR/C# (such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045))
and more specifically about WPF (i recommend either [WPF 4 Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331195) or [Pro WPF in C# 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430272058))

also, u can find nice code samples at [WPF samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B0%5D.Value=WPF)

And ,finally, u should necessarily code ur own programs: more code - more experience